# Is there a way to find where I have made some comments earlier or recently?

Tags: support, comments, search

It would be better if someone can tell me a way through which I can find the post by myself rather than being completely dependent on moderators or the Stack Exchange team. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can do a SEDE query to search through comments. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210112/380389.

Comment: It does not help now, but it is advised to keep a notes document   with references to comments (and other content, yours and others') that you think you *might* want to reference or reuse in the future (if nothing else, because posts (with comments) and comments may be deleted at any time). Save a copy of the most valuable content in the same document (or elsewhere if it is too big).

Answer (score 4):

In general, to find the comments you have posted *without* someone else randomly linking you to them, you can follow these easy steps:

1. Go to your profile
2. Click on the "Activity" tab
3. Click on "All actions"
4. Click on "Comments"

This list is organized by most to least recent. So if you know approximately when you made the comment, it should be easy to find. Otherwise, if you have a lot of comments, you might have to use the SE Data Explorer as indicated by Glorfindel.

It should be noted that this list does not show comments on deleted posts. Additionally, comments are by their very nature only temporary. If a comment does not show up on the list, consider the very real possibility that it no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've found the correct account, [this page in your profile shows all your comments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/274807/david?tab=activity&sort=comments). They are in chronological order so if you know roughly when you posted the comment it should be easy to find. I don't think there is any way to search the list of comments.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [list of comments in your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=comments). In your case, it's quite short (only 26) so you should be able to find your comment (unless it has been deleted).

[image]

Searching within those comments is not possible, you'll probably need the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to do so.